# OpenMP not in NetBeans IDE 7.0

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, openmp

The title is fairly self explanatory...  isn't anywhere to be found in the version I have (the latest), and all searches on the web have turned up little to nothing in the way of real solutions. There is only a pdf file which explains that omp flags must be marked in the C compiler I use, but I can't even get that far because I can't find the library anywhere!

Is there just a way to pull the library from somewhere and load it in? Or do I need an entirely new gcc file for my IDE to pull from, and if so, where do I get it?

EDIT: Still no luck searching. I'm also willing to work with a different IDE similar to NetBeans... preferably one that uses the Cygwin compiler set as well. If anyone has any suggestions on what I could use that would support OMP, I would be more than willing to entertain them.

Comment: openmp is a compiler extension, so you need to provide the flag `-fopenmp` to gcc. Did you do that? I think you don't have to provide special libraries, at least last time I tried openmp on linux I didn't had to.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Solaris Studio on Solaris (SPARC and x86) and Linux (x86) provides an IDE with C/C++/Fortran compilers with OpenMP 3.0 enabled, and a debugger and performance analyzer that understand OpenMP.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/index.html

And, it's a free download and free to use.